# Which phpMyAdmin is compatible with PHP version 5.1.6?

Tags: php

Have to install phpMyAdmin on a serverspace that is not running php 5.2+ therefore I cannot use the latest release of MyAdmin.

Updating PHP is not an option unfortunately.

Which is the most recent compatible version?

Comment: "Updating PHP is not an option" means "being horribly insecure is an option", which always seemed kinda odd to me. PHP 5.1 stopped receiving security updates **7 years, 3 months ago**.

Comment: You need to fix whatever is causing you to be unable to update PHP. This is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Incidentally, even if PHP 5.1 weren't horribly insecure, the ancient versions of phpMyAdmin you'll need to run to use 5.1 **are**. You're gonna get hacked.

Comment: If this is CentOS/RHEL 5, it  still comes with PHP 5.1.6 per default (these packages still get security patches from upstream till 2017). That said, if you have root access, I'd suggest to update to PHP 5.3, as in the meantime CentOS/RHEL 5 is also providing packages for this, called php53-xxx.

Answer (score 3):

Checking the `Documentation.txt` files from the [downloads from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/files/phpMyAdmin/) the latest I was able to find that supports something lower than PHP 5.2.0 is 2.11.11.3.

```
phpMyAdmin 2.11.11.3 Documentation

  * phpMyAdmin homepage
  * SourceForge phpMyAdmin project page
  * Official phpMyAdmin wiki
  * Local documents:
      + Version history: ChangeLog
      + General notes: README
      + License: LICENSE
  * Documentation version: $Id$

Requirements

  * PHP
      + You need PHP 4.2.0 or newer, with session support (see FAQ 1.31)
      + You need GD2 support in PHP to display inline thumbnails of JPEGs
        ("image/jpeg: inline") with their original aspect ratio
      + You need PHP 4.3.0 or newer to use the "text/plain: external"
        MIME-based transformation
      + When using the "cookie" authentication method, the mcrypt extension is
        strongly suggested for most users and is required for 64?bit machines.
        Not using mcrypt will cause phpMyAdmin to load pages significantly
        slower.
  * MySQL 3.23.32 or newer (details);
  * Web browser with cookies enabled.
```